# Learning to end sentences with "hence". Examples?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, descriptive-grammar

I dabble in creative writing here and there. Wordsmiths like Tolkien and Lovecraft are a pleasure to read for their sheer skill in sentence structure and plethora of words.

I'm now attempting to learn how to end sentences with "hence". I saw such a sentence recently and I enjoyed it very much. But while I've looked at the meaning to be "from here" as an archaic usage of the word, I don't entirely have a feeling and inner understanding for how this structure works. Normally I'd improve this by reading and exposing myself to it, but alas, in this case, there aren't many hence-ending sentences I'm able to find.

So I ask you here, to give me some examples of them.
Or perhaps, point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: The phrasings in your question remind me of the speech patterns of Albert, German husband to Queen Victoria, in the Masterpiece Theater program: https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/masterpiece/shows/victoria/

Comment: I disagree. I tried to read Tolkien aloud to my children and it was a nightmare. An acquaintance had the same experience. Gives you a different view of things.

Comment: Your closing sentence can be rewritten as a request to *point you hence*.

Comment: @TRomano I've not seen it. I'm not sure if that's a good or a bad thing now.

Comment: @David, de gustibus non est disputandum, I guess.

Comment: @Lawrence "Or perhaps, point me in the right direction, hence." Like that?

Comment: @David Despite Tolkien’s work being initially created for the benefit of his own children, I don’t think the majority of it is really very suitable as material to be read aloud to children. That doesn’t mean it can’t be a pleasure to read, though; just that its audience is not generally small children. I first tried to read Shakespeare on my own when I was about 10, and it was completely hopeless. Then I tried again around 15 and found it difficult and not very enjoyable. Then I tried again in my twenties and found it highly enjoyable.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet — Not the suitability for children, the suitability for reading aloud. I kept having to go back and re-read sentences because of false scent and what I consider poor construction. In contrast, reading Charles Dickens...

Comment: @Ehrendil No, not like that.

Comment: @Lawrence Please correct me.

Comment: Why do you particularly want to use 'hence' at the _end_ of the sentence?

Comment: @KateBunting I simply enjoyed the structure. It seemed old-fashioned, overly formal, and fanciful.

Comment: The answers below do a pretty good job of it.

Comment: @Lawrence the answers give excellent examples. I agree. But I still don't know how one would end my final sentence in the initial question with "hence".

Comment: Pretend the word is “there”. You can say “point me there” with no comma. *Hence* is used the same way if you intend to use the word as a direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word **hence** can have a temporal meaning similar to "down the road" or "later":

> The order was placed in January and the products were shipped *three months hence*.
>
> You take out a loan for $10,000 and by the time it is paid off *five years hence*, you will have paid the bank quite a lot of money in interest.

That meaning is not "archaic" but it is definitely old-fashioned.

The spatial use is more of an archaism.

> On the 15th of that month the vessel *sailed hence*.

The vessel sailed away; sailed from here.

Comment: _The order was placed in January and the products were shipped three months hence._  'Hence means 'from here', so in a sentenced referring to the past you would need to use 'thence'. 'Three months hence' is 'three months from today'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: **hence** does not always mean "from *now*".  It is sometimes used to mean merely "later on" (i.e. from *that point*). Compare: https://books.google.com/books?id=j5zv4thxr2oC&pg=PA58&dq=%22six+months+hence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLgfL1rL7gAhXrUd8KHfqVCjM4FBDoAQhgMAo#v=onepage&q=%22six%20months%20hence%22&f=false   The "origo" can be projected just as it can be with **now**; *And they came now to a stream.*

Comment: See also: https://books.google.com/books?id=JY03BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA259&dq=%22six+months+hence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLgfL1rL7gAhXrUd8KHfqVCjM4FBDoAQh6MA4#v=onepage&q=%22six%20months%20hence%22&f=false or this: https://books.google.com/books?id=Lq8yAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22six+months+hence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLgfL1rL7gAhXrUd8KHfqVCjM4FBDoAQiAATAP#v=onepage&q=%22six%20months%20hence%22&f=false or this: https://books.google.com/books?id=vx0--MaCdzAC&pg=PA97&dq=%22six+months+hence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNrNWWr77gAhXlm-AKHQmYADc4KBDoAQhGMAU#v=onepage&q=%22six%20months%20hence%22&f=false

Comment: I find that usage very odd.

Answer (score 2):

The OED has a score of them, among their many examples, including from Shakespeare.

> Etymology: Middle English hennes , etc., < the earlier henne , hen
>   adv., with adverbial genitive suffix -es, -s, as in -ward, -wards,
>   etc. The spelling hence is phonetic, to retain the breath sound
>   denoted in the earlier spelling by s, as in once, twice, mice, pence,
>   defence, etc.
>
> I. Of place.
>    1.
>
> a. (Away) from here, from this place; to a distance. c1290   S. Eng.
>   Leg. I. 41/231   Ich it wolle hennes lede. c1300  (▸?a1200)    Laȝamon
>   Brut (Otho) (1963) l. 792   Hare we hinnes [c1275 Calig. heonne]
>   wende. c1300   Beket 998   Go hunnes. c1330   R. Mannyng Chron. Wace
>   16562   To Cornewaille þey fledden hennes. 1382   Bible (Wycliffite,
>   E.V.) Gen. xlii. 15   Ȝe shulen not goon hens, to the tyme that ȝoure
>   leest brother come. c1440   York Myst. xxii. 3   High you hense. c1450
>   (▸c1400)    Sowdon of Babylon (1881) l. 1922   Elles come we nevere
>   hennys oute. 1559   W. Baldwin et al. Myrroure for Magistrates Suffolk
>   xii   In wit and learning matcheles hence to Grece. c1560   A. Scott
>   Poems (S.T.S.) xx. 57   Thairfoir go hens in haist. a1616
>   Shakespeare Two Gentlemen of Verona (1623) i. ii. 60   How churlishly,
>   I chid Lucetta hence .    1634   T. Herbert Relation Some Yeares
>   Trauaile 214   Hence our journey led vs homewards in fiue dayes sayle.
>   1808   Scott Marmion vi. xxiii   Hence might they see the full array
>   of either host.
>
> ```
> b. At a distance from here; away. c1330   Assump. Virg. (B.M. MS.) 328   I was fer hens atte my prechinge. 1393   Langland Piers Plowman
> ```
>
> C. vi. 80   Lyf-holynesse and loue, han ben longe hennes. 1560   J.
>   Heywood Fourth Hundred Epygrams ii. sig. Aiv   Ye haue..taryde longe
>   hence. 1595   Spenser Colin Clouts come Home Againe sig. A3v   Whilest
>   thou wast hence. a1616   Shakespeare Winter's Tale (1623) iv. iii. 80 
>   I haue a Kinsman not past three quarters of a mile hence .
>
> ```
> c. with redundant from (†fro). c1340   Cursor M. (Trin.) 1264   Þi gate Fro hennes to paradis ȝate. a1425  (▸c1395)    Bible (Wycliffite,
> ```
>
> L.V.) (Royal) (1850) Gen. xlii. 15   Ȝe schulen not go fro hennus.
>   1477   Caxton in Earl Rivers tr. Dictes or Sayengis Philosophhres
>   (1877) lf. 73v   Socrates was..boren in a ferre Contre from hens. 1526
>   Bible (Tyndale) Luke iv. f. lxxix   Cast thy silfe doune from hens.
>   1597   Shakespeare Richard II iii. iii. 6   Richard not farre from
>   hence hath hid his head.    1718   J. Addison Remarks Italy (ed. 2) 4 
>   We sailed from hence directly for Genoa. 1792   T. Jefferson Writings
>   (1859) III. 489   It being impossible to prescribe them from hence.
>   1820   W. Irving Sketch Bk. I. 171   From hence I was conducted up a
>   staircase to a suite of apartments.
>
> 2. with ellipsis of vb. of motion, chiefly as a command: hence! go hence, depart. hence with: go away with, take away. 1573–80   J. Baret
>      Aluearie H. 392   Hence, away, apage te. 1582   R. Stanyhurst tr.
>      Virgil First Foure Bookes Æneis ii. 41   Let vs hence. 1593
>      Shakespeare Venus & Adonis sig. D   I pray you hence, and leaue me
>      here alone.    a1616   Shakespeare Tempest (1623) i. ii. 477   Hence:
>      hang not on my garments.    a1616   Shakespeare Winter's Tale (1623)
>      ii. iii. 68   Hence with her, out o'dore.    1638   Milton Lycidas in
>      Obsequies 20 in Justa Edouardo King   Hence with deniall vain, and coy
>      excuse. 1769   T. Gray Ode at Installation Duke of Grafton 12   Hence,
>      away, 'tis holy ground! 1855   R. Browning Grammarian's Funeral 112
>      Hence with life's pale lure!
> 3. a. spec. From this world, from this life. c1315   Shoreham 83   That no fend ous ne schende Nou, ne wanne the tyme comthe Thet we
>      scholle hennes wende. c1450   Lay Folks Mass Bk. (MS. F.) 121   And
>      for the saules that hennes be past. 1583   P. Stubbes Second Pt. Anat.
>      Abuses sig. M2   When God shall call them hence to himselfe. 1611
>      Bible (King James) Psalms xxxix. 13   Before I goe hence, and be no
>      more.    1871   B. Jowett tr. Plato Dialogues I. 415   They go from
>      hence into the other world.   b. Elsewhere (than in this world); in
>      the next world. Obsolete. ▸ c1426   J. Audelay Poems (1931) 11   Hit
>      schal be ponyschid here ore hennus euere trespasse. 1604   Shakespeare
>      Hamlet iii. ii. 211   Both heere and hence pursue me lasting strife,
>      If once I be a widdow, euer I be a wife.    a1616   Shakespeare King
>      John (1623) iv. ii. 89   This must be answer'd either heere, or hence
>      .
>
>    II. Of time.
> 4. a. From this time onward, henceforward, henceforth. Also with from (†fro). arch. and poet. c1380   Eng. Wycliffite Serm. in Sel. Wks. II.
>      17   From hens bigan Jesus to preche. c1384   Chaucer Hous of Fame
>      iii. 194   Fro hennes in to domes day. 1598   Shakespeare Love's
>      Labour's Lost v. ii. 808   Hence herrite then my hart, is in thy
>      brest.    a1616   Shakespeare Othello (1622) iii. iii. 384   From
>      hence, I'le loue no friend, since loue breedes such offence.    1633
>      P. Fletcher Purple Island xii. lxxxviii. 180   Hence mayst thou freely
>      play. 1817   Shelley Laon & Cythna ix. xvi. 201   That the rule of men
>      was over now, And hence, the subject world to woman's will must bow.
>      †b. (At some time in the past reckoned) from now; in quot. 1393   =
>      since, ago. Obsolete. rare. 1393   Langland Piers Plowman C. vi. 35
>      Whanne ich ȝong was..meny ȝer hennes. 1610   Bp. J. Hall Common Apol.
>      against Brownists xiii. 34   But you leape backe..from hence to the
>      Apostles times.
>      c. (At some time in the future) from now. a1616   Shakespeare Comedy of Errors (1623) iii. i. 123   Ile meet you at that place some
>      houre hence .    a1735   J. Arbuthnot Hist. John Bull (1988) V. Pref.
>      93   Let not posterity a thousand years hence look for truth in the
>      voluminous annals of pedants. 1885   Manch. Examiner 12 Oct. 5/1   We
>      have to..think of what our position will be five years hence.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone familiar with the Authorised King James translation of the Bible will no doubt remember Acts 1:5 which ends with ...

> not many days hence.

Meaning not many days into the future, or not many days from now.

And then there is the last few words of John chapter fourteen which ends with Jesus' words ...

> Aride, let us go hence.

Meaning, let us go from here.

There are other expressions,  not at the end of sentences, in the KJV .. 'remove hence', 'depart hence', 'take these things hence' and one unusual one in James 4:1 ...

> From whence come wars and fightings among you ? Come they not hence, even of your own desires ... etc.

'Come they not hence' appears to mean, 'Come they not here'. Which seems a little odd to me, for I thought the meaning of 'hence' was 'from here'.

I have cheated, of course, and used a concordance. I didn't do this from memory.

Comment: I think we can understand it as "from there" rather than "(to) here". You will encounter "They came hence hither".

Comment: @NigelJ 'Come they not hence?' means 'Don't they come from here?' (i.e. the quarrels come from you yourselves).

Comment: @TRomano Hence = from here. Thence = from there. Hither = to here. Thither = to there.

Comment: @Kate Bunting:  **hence** can also mean "away (from *there*) "

Comment: In the sense of "away from *that place*" (but not hither)

Comment: @TRomano In what dictionary  have you found _hence_ defined as _from there_?

Comment: See this example: https://books.google.com/books?id=YUdEAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA30&dq=%22miles+hence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9nN28hL7gAhUI2FkKHZudAiwQ6AEISDAF#v=onepage&q=%22miles%20hence%22&f=false *Six miles over a tolerable good road, with one bad hill brought us to a small branch of good water, where we nooned. Seven miles hence over a bad road, with some bad hills, passing the Oregon Rapids, and we camped on the bottom: grass scarce; wood and water plenty.*   The meaning could be paraphrased as "(from there) further on ".

Comment: And although I don't have my hand on one at the moment, I'm sure there are attestations detailing a past itinerary where phrases like "and we sailed hence on to X place", where "hence" refers to a location that is not the speaker's present location. The *hence/thence* distinction is not always a perfectly clear cut one.